# Confirmation email when deleting account

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've made an App with Firebase to Auth User and I want to allow them to delete their account if they want. Is it possible to send a confirmation email to delete current user account or if I use the delete function it delete the account instantly without any confirmation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the [delete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#delete) method on a user object as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#delete_a_user), the result is instant, without any confirmation required by the user.  If you want to add a confirmation step, you will have to implement that yourself.